# Does non-rotating object have rotational inertia if it is attach to rotating object by a spring

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotation

My question relating to the Rotational Inertia as a whole system. As I learn that the Rotational Inertia is defined for a rotating object to an fixed axis but I got problem in the case a rotating object is attach to normal object.

Considering this case: a disk which have Rotational Inertia I, the rotating axis place at its center of mass. Now the disk is wrapped by a string that attach to an object mass m.

Now as the disk rotate, the object will also move but as you can see, that because the disk is attach to m so its angular speed will not be the same as it is when it's free as well as its angular acceleration when a specific torque applied to it. So I can say that the Rotational Inertia actually changed but when the object m is not really rotate but move straightly so I can't calculate the Rotational Inertia of the system.

As the object m move close to the rotating axis because of rotation; then, does the Rotational Inertia change. I mean; if the Rotational Inertia can be defined so when the object move closer to the axis, will the Rotational Inertia change?

I want to understand this problem in order to be able to derived a certain formula for the force acting on the m object

Comment: by rotational inertia, do you mean moment of inertia? or angular momentum?

Comment: I think it's moment of inertia. The book I'm using don't use moment of inertia but it use angular momentum and rotational inertia separately so rotational inertia means moment of inertia

Comment: The moment of inertia depends on both the shape of the object and the axis of rotation. In this example there is no single axis of rotation for the entire system (the mass doesnt strictly rotate around the center of the disk), so I would not use the moment of inertia of the whole system, but rather only for the disk and then consider the interaction of the disk and the mass.

Comment: That's what I concern because the mass m don't rotate about the center of the disk. But the mass m surely affect to rotation speed or acceleration of the disk. But again, we use Moment of inertia in rotating motion (the disk) and mass for non-rotating motion. They have different unit so I don't know how to deal with this case

Comment: is there gravity present?

Comment: Yes, the gravity present but assume that there is no frictional force between the object, the disk and the floor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18607/discussion-between-aukxn-and-julian-fernandez).

Comment: just give me a few more details (a graph would be great and what force you want to calculate), it will be faster for me to just solve it for you.